# How to rotate an element 180 in react?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, css-transitions, react-component

How can I rotate a [`<CaretUpFill/>`](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/caret-up-fill/) icon to be upside down based a state variable `show`, but in a transition? I'm in a `_rafce`. (react arrow function component)

Currently, I am rendering another icon `<CaretDownFill/>`, but it doesn't look smooth.
[image]

I want to make the arrow look like this:

[image]

```js
        <div className="col-2 d-flex align-items-center">
          <small>{show ? <CaretUpFill /> : <CaretDownFill />}</small>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [style prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html) to add a [CSS transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) to rotate the icon with a [CSS transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) to animate the transition.

```
const style = {
 transform: show ? 'rotate(180deg)' : '', 
 transition: 'transform 150ms ease', // smooth transition
}

<div className="col-2 d-flex align-items-center">
 <small><CaretUpFill style={style}/></small>
</div>

//if the icon doesn't have access to style props you can add it to the <small> element
<div className="col-2 d-flex align-items-center">
 <small style={style}><CaretUpFill /></small>
</div>
```

You could also use a third party library like [Framer Motion](https://www.framer.com/motion/) to animate your components - but it is overkill for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "rotate" function with CSS, this is the easiest way:

```
style={{ transform: 'rotate(180deg)' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

use css property:

`transform: rotate(180deg)`

I see that you've created two elements - `<CaretUpFill />` and `<CaretDownFill />`.

What you're doing now is basically unmounting the `<CaretUpFill />` and mounting the `<CaretDownFill />` component (and vice versa), but to my knowledge it's impossible to create an animation between two separate components.

Therefore, I recommend using just one component, and adding an animation by using the css property above.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you framer-motion library
You can rotate elements, and do a lot of manipulations.
Which difference between `css` and `framer motion`? Motion its js components, working fine

Here is [example](https://www.framer.com/api/motion/examples/)